# Ubuntu server: Apache status show old failure information, and is running fine

Tags: apache, server, status, systemctl

I am a bit puzzled about this... **Apache status is showing information from 12 days ago**. It's running fine and website is working. Is the status command not supposed to show current state of Apache?

```
# systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-01-05 05:19:24 CET; 1 weeks 5 days ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 514 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 05 05:19:24 serverX systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 05 05:19:24 serverX apachectl[532]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/some/dir] does not exist
Jan 05 05:19:24 serverX apachectl[532]: (99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 10.42.24.6:80
Jan 05 05:19:24 serverX apachectl[532]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jan 05 05:19:24 serverX apachectl[532]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jan 05 05:19:24 serverX apachectl[514]: Action 'start' failed.
Jan 05 05:19:24 serverX apachectl[514]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jan 05 05:19:24 serverX systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 05 05:19:24 serverX systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 05 05:19:24 serverX systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

OS: Ubuntu 20

netstat shows that port 80 is actually listening on 10.42.24.6

```
# netstat -tulpn | grep apache
tcp        0      0 10.42.24.6:80           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1557/apache2        
tcp        0      0 10.42.24.6:443          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1557/apache2
```

Also Apache is logging requests to the access logs

I noticed this problem, because I am using `systemctl status apache2` to check apache status in a new shell script I wrote... But the way this command is working, makes it useless.

Comment: check the message:  make_sock: could not bind to address 10.42.24.6:80

Comment: @TelinovDmitri check the date ... The information is from january 5. Apache is running fine. Why do I see old info when running `systemctl status apache2` ?

Comment: Guys... please read and understand the post, before you vote to close it.

Comment: apache from systemd unit file cannot bind to a port, what it the problem with date? Just restart it and check the date again.... Maybe it was ran in other way, so it keeps the port open?

Comment: @TelinovDmitri ... You are focusing on the error. Forget the error.... The problem is that Apache is running fine and is bound to that port. But when I run the status command, it says that Apache is not running... That is not correct. This means that i cannot use `systemctl status apache2` as a reliable way to check apache status.